# makefile with conditionally generated file

Tags: c++, makefile, prerequisites

How do I convey to `make` that a script can conditionally modify a file, so that `make` waits to `stat` all the files until that script finishes running?

---

Consider the following toy example series of files:

```
// version
2
```

```
// foo.h - note the space between the 1 and the semicolon
static constexpr int VERSION = 1 ;
```

```
//update.py
import sys 

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    cur = int(f.readlines()[0].split()[5])

with open('version') as f:
    exp = int(f.readlines()[0].strip())

if cur < exp:
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'w') as f:
        print >> f, 'static constexpr int VERSION = {} ;'.format(exp)
```

```
// main.cxx
#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << VERSION << std::endl;
}
```

```
// makefile
all : a.out updater

a.out : main.o
    g++ -o a.out main.o

main.o : main.cxx
    g++ -std=c++11 -o main.o -c main.cxx -MP -MMD -MF main.d

.PHONY : updater
updater :
    python update.py foo.h

-include main.d
```

The intent here is that I have a file, `foo.h`, which is *conditionally* updated by a script, `update.py` (if you increase the number in `version`, `foo.h` will be updated - otherwise nothing will happen). I would like to convey this notion to `make` somehow - that it is not to `stat` `foo.h` in order to determine if it needs to remake `main.o` until `update.py` finishes running. How do I ensure that ordering?

Note: `version` here is simply a placeholder for a complex series of prerequisites that are not easy to express. Simply adding `foo.h : version` is not a solution.

Comment: `foo.h: updater` perhaps? Or even just make the recipe for `updater` the recipe for `foo.h`.

Comment: @user657267 That doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong about moving the recipe to `foo.h`, but making `foo.h` the target of `main.o`, and `updater` the target of `foo.h` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you don't want make to update `main.o` etc. until after `foo.h` has been updated you have to list `foo.h` as a prerequisite:

```
main.o : main.cxx foo.h
        g++ -std=c++11 -o main.o -c main.cxx -MP -MMD -MF main.d
```

(Although of course I would never write it like this, I would always use variables like this:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11
DEPFLAGS = -MP -MMD -MF $*.d

main.o : main.cxx foo.h
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(DEPFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

but that's me...)

Second, you have to have a rule to update `foo.h`.  As you suggest, it should be `.PHONY` so it's always run, even though it doesn't always update `foo.h`:

```
.PHONY: updater
updater:
        python update.py foo.h
```

Now you have to connect these two rules, so you have to create a rule that links `foo.h` to `updater`:

```
foo.h : updater ;
```

Note the semicolon here, that's *critical*.  The way it works is this: `updater` is phony so it will always run, and that means that any target the depends on it will always run.  So clearly you can't list `main.o : main.cxx updater` as that would rebuild `main.o` every time.

So you can introduce an intermediate rule, `foo.h : updater`.  You need to do this anyway since you need to list `foo.h` as a prerequisite so you need a target to build it.

However, by itself this won't help because make sees that there's no recipe to build `foo.h`, so it doesn't realize that when `updater` was run it built `foo.h`.  You get around this by creating an empty recipe for `foo.h`; that's what the `;` is for:

```
foo.h : updater ;
```

that creates an empty recipe for this target `foo.h` and that's enough to get make to check to see whether the file `foo.h` has been modified or not.  When it is modified (by `updater`) then `main.o` will be rebuilt.  When it is not modified, `main.o` will not be rebuilt (unless there's some other reason to rebuild it).

Comment: A semicolon makes all the difference! You can remove the first part of the answer, the prereq of `foo.h` is handled by `-include main.d`

Comment: That's not good enough for generated files, because the first time you run `make` there won't be any `.d` files, so make won't know that anything depends on `foo.h`, so `foo.h` won't be created then you'll get a compile error trying to compile and build the first `.d` files.  Unless you're saying that `foo.h` always exists but may also be automatically updated...?  That's a bit... odd... usually people using SCM systems don't like to check in automatically-updated files like that.  Also, even then it won't try to update `foo.h` the first time.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to rebuild `main.o` and `a.out` when and only when the script modifies `foo.h`, this might be a job for **recursive Make:**

```
all : updater
    @$(MAKE) a.out                      

...

main.o : main.cxx foo.h
   ...
```

Comment: This does work (+1), but I'd like to avoid recursive make here.